# Errors with gstreamer, glib and gtk.

Tags: c++, gtk, shared-libraries, gstreamer

I had code that compiled on Ubuntu-10.04 and whatever I had installed  with it.  I let synaptic upgrade me 12.04 and now I get these errors when compiling a c++ Gstreamer program.  The code builds a .so on linux and cross compiles a .dll on windows.  The so implements a type of intercom.

```
(process:18707): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.3
/./gobject/gtype.c:2722: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:18707): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 
`result != 0' failed

(process:18707): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.3
/./gobject/gtype.c:2722: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:18707): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 
`result != 0' failed

(process:18707): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 
`GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
```

In my code I have a class that contains the receiver pipeline and another class for the sender pipeline.  The actual Gstreamer stuff is in run() methods launched in separate threads.

The point these errors are thrown is the first call to the either consgtructor (they're symmetrical) where I have declared some GstXXXX (e.g. GstElement) variables but have not yet launched the other thread.  That takes a call to the start() method.

I tried using gtk_init() as one forum entry advised.  I added all the pkg-config calls to eclipse, but it still say gtk_init() is an unknown call.  Obviously I don't quite have that working, but I **shouldn't** need it.  I didn't used to.  I have it commented out right now.

So, can someone suggest what might be causing gtk/gst to complain.

I noted that g_type_init() is deprecated after version 2.36 of glib (I think they meant glib).  So, how can I tell which version of glib is installed?

Comment: Thinking about this, it makes even less sense.  I have other, very similar, gstreamer apps that comppile just fine.  I'm off to do some snooping with the debugger.

Comment: I don't get your problem: why you just not add `g_type_init()` as suggested by the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Mea Culpa.  I had a call that referenced an as-yet uncreated gvariable.  Dumb.  All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

You must have installed an old glib, since in newer version, there is no such warning. Find all glib libraries on your computer, rename them one by one and build, then you can find out which one is working for your project now. Then check your build option and related .pc file of glib to find out how is the wrong library involved in your build.
The warning is defined in gtype.c as 
                g_log (G_LOG_DOMAIN, G_LOG_LEVEL_CRITICAL,                            \
                       "%s: You forgot to call g_type_init()",                        \
                       G_STRLOC);                                                     \

Answer (score 0):

For others with this error, make sure you're calling gst_init.